# List of all devices connected to "Internet Sharing" Hotspot

Tags: macos, airport, internet-sharing, tethering

How Can I know which devices connected my hotspot.
Or Where I can find list of connected devices to my hotspot.

Comment: What kind of hotspot are you looking at here? Your WiFi router, your Mac offering Internet Sharing, your iOS device with Personal Hotspot enabled or something completely different?

Comment: Mac's by default internet Sharing option.